# Why there is a overflow with Swift language when assign a 8 bits binary value to a var of Int8 type?

Tags: swift, overflow

When I write this line in playground:

```
let firstBits: Int8 = 0b11111111
```

There is an error: Integer literal overflows when stored into 'Int8'

Since Int8 is a Signed Value and its range is from -128 to 127. The first bit from left is for  the single (minus or plus), and the other 7 bits stand for the value. So there should be total 8 bits in the binary format. But why there is an error?

If I write like this with 7 bits:

```
let firstBits: Int8 = 0b1111111
```

There is no error and firstBits' value is 127.

So how should I assign -128 to firstBits with binary format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I am not experienced with Swift, I can safely assume that the binary literal does *not* represent the binary representation, but only the value. So 0b11111111 will still be 255. If you want -128, you should use -0b10000000.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks a lot! To assign a negative value, we need to put a minus before the binary format value and then can fill 8 bits. At that time, if write like this: `let firstBits: Int8 = -0b10000001`, the overflow error shows up again.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize it as follows:

```
let firstBits: Int8 = -0b10000000
```

Comment: That's right. Thanks for pointing that out, I did my tests with -1 and left it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As already said `0b11111111` is the integer constant 255 and that is not representable
as an `Int8`. But the Swift integer types have a new constructor now
which creates a signed integer from an unsigned number with the same bit pattern:

```
let foo = Int8(bitPattern: 0b11111111) // -1
let bar = Int8(bitPattern: 0b10000000) // -128
```